# BASH: get the second position of an indirect referenced array

Tags: arrays, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
ARRAY1=(STRING1 STRING2 STRING3);


STRING1=(zero one);
STRING2=(zero one two three);
STRING3=(zero one two three four);
    
echo ${!ARRAY1[1]}
```

In the code above, doing indirect reference, only returns the value at the position 0 of the indirect referenced array,
I need the simplest possible solution for this situation:

Get the string at position x of ARRAY1 then, by indirect reference, get
the position 2 at the array STRING2, which should return the value "two".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using indirect references for arrays, the variable that holds the name of the array must *also* include the index, brackets and all, as well. It's as if an array is just a collection of similarly named parameters, rather than a single name which can take an indexing operator.

```
$ name=${ARRAY[1]}[2]
$ echo $name
STRING2[2]
$ echo "${!name}"
two
```

---

`${!ARRAY1[1]}` is interpreted as follows. `ARRAY1[1]` is, in fact, used as if it were the name of a parameter. Since `${ARRAY1[1]}` expands to `STRING2`, the indirect expansion is treated the same as `${STRING2}`. The expansion of an array *sans* index is identical to accessing the 0th element, i.e., `${STRING2[0]}`.

To see this in action, change the value of the first element of each `STRING` array to something unique, then look at the value of `${!ARRAY1[0]}`, `${!ARRAY1[1]}`, and `${!ARRAY1[2]}`. It should be obvious that they are equivalent to `${STRING1}`, `${STRING2}`, and `${STRING3}`, respectively, so that each expands to the first element of the corresponding array.